# How to change the way a copy-paste text behaves?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and I wish to present some lines of code in there,but I can't find a stylish way to do it. For example let's take a simple HelloProgram written in JAVA. I want to make it appear like so

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        add (new GLabel("I love Java." ,100,75));
        add( new GLabel(" Marios Theofilos" ,600,450));
        // The x and y coοrdinates may vary depending on your computer
    }
}
```

and not like that

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {public void run() {
add (new GLabel("I love Java." ,100,75));
add( new GLabel(" Marios Theofilos" ,600,450));
}
}
```

.Basically, just using copy paste does not work. I have tried text-aligning in both CSS and HTML. The best possible solution seems to be to make a div box and then put the code there. I've tried creating the box,but I wasn't able to change the way the text behaved when I copy and paste. Also, I can't create the desired effect by hand,or I haven't found out how yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what the `<pre>` tag is there for: to render preformatted text:

```
<pre>
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {
    public void run() {
        add (new GLabel("I love Java." ,100,75));
        add( new GLabel(" Marios Theofilos" ,600,450));
        // The x and y coοrdinates may vary depending on your computer
    }
}
</pre>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

Take care to `htmlescape()` the content when you create the node programmatically!

Comment: Thanks a million. Could you care to explain what htmlescape()  is?

Comment: Imagine your embedded java code contains a character that is part of the html markup. Take a `<` for example. That would corrupt the html markup, obviously. To prevent such characters to be interpreted by the html interpreter but to be left alone and displayed instead, you have to "escape" them. This is typically done by using the ampersand notation, `&lt;` in this case. Most programming languages bring functions for this, so you do not have to do it manually if you, as said, create the node programmatically. Just pump the code to be displayed through such an escaping function.